# Python wsgi:ssl-error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, wsgi, digital-ocean

I just migrated from Amazon ec2 instance to DigitalOcean droplet.
Everything seems to be working fine until I ran into the SSL problem when I configure my python app, WSGI and apache2.

Droplet: Ubuntu 16.04
Python version: 2.7.12

VirtualHost file

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi                                                           
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                       
ServerName c123456.com                                                               
#translatr.varunmalhotra.xyz                                                         

#DocumentRoot /var/www/html                                                          
#ErrorDocument 404 /notFound404.html                                                 
ErrorLog /var/log/translatr.error.log                                                
CustomLog /var/log/translatr.access.log combined                                     

WSGIDaemonProcess translatrapp python-path=/var/www/html/translatr:/var/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages                                                    
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/translatr/translatrapp.wsgi                          

<Directory /var/www/html/translatr>                                                  
    WSGIProcessGroup translatrapp                                                    
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}                                                   
    Order deny,allow                                                                 
    Allow from all                                                                   
</Directory>
```

```

My app uses python `requests` module to make a GET request.
The requests return `500` and when I check my logs, I could see

```
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754636 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     request
 = requests.get(link, headers=agents, verify=False)                                      
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754641 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get   
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754645 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     return 
request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)                                             
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754650 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in reques
t                                                                                        
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754655 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     respons
e = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)                                    
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754659 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in 
request                                                                                  
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754664 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     resp = 
self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                                           
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754669 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 597, in 
send                                                                                     
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754673 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     history
 = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []                                     
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754678 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 195, in 
resolve_redirects                                                                        
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754683 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     **adapt
er_kwargs                                                                                
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754687 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in 
send                                                                                     
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754692 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     r = ada
pter.send(request, **kwargs)                                                             
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754697 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]   File "/va
r/www/html/translatr/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 433, in 
send                                                                                     
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754702 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680]     raise S
SLError(e, request=request)                                                              │
[Sat Jan 28 10:46:23.754706 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 6627:tid 139754554279680] SSLError: C│
an't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

I have searched a lot.
I have tried installing `openssl`, other conf, but really frustrated.
I don't know how it's working smooth in Amazon ec2 but not in Droplet.

Any help in a good direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How did you get the python build you're using right now? Did you install the binary from Ubuntu's package manager?

Comment: I used http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu to install python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was something wrong with my python version installed. Either there were multiple python versions installed or the build was not properly built. I was on `Ubuntu 16.04 digitalOcean machine` which comes without `python` installation. So I had to install it manually. I followed the answer given on https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu

But, nothing seemed to work.

Finally, I created a fresh new machine but this time, it was `Ubuntu 14.04` which comes with `python` being already installed. When I installed the dependencies and deployed my Flask app, it worked properly.

**Changed Ubuntu 16.04(without python) to Ubuntu 14.04(with python installed).**

Answer (score 8):

If you installed Python from the source you'll have to rerun

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

AFTER you have installed openssl (I'm assuming through `sudo apt install openssl`).

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned. But it didn't work. Any reasons, why?

Comment: Hmm no idea then. Glad you found a workaround though.

Comment: To make sure you have openssl and all other dependencies for compiling python3.6, I used this on my Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo apt-get install build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had a hell of a time (Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.7), but managed to get it to work eventually:

```
apt install libssl libssl-dev
# compile Python from source:
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.7.5.tgz
./configure --with-openssl=/openssl/  # make sure that this is where x509_vfy.h sits
make && make altinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used `sudo pip install` to solve this problem in CentOS7

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After installing *openssl* and *opessl-devel*, there is no need to configure python again.

Run the following commands:

```
make 
make install
```